# Rails Facebook-omniauth, Devise - Why can't I use environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I had omniauth with Devise working in my app, but then I moved my Facebook Credentials into environment variables, and I've checked in the console to make sure they are defined. I started seeing this show up in my server logs:

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Error validating client secret.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

when I try to have test users authenticate with Facebook. I've checked my APP_ID AND APP_SECRET. Both are set and match the credentials in my FB developer dashboard.

I also tried deleting my Facebook app and creating a brand new one (updated ID and SECRET).

I also tried to create new users who hadn't authed with omniauth yet, with no luck.

Lastly, I tried reverting back to hardcoded Facebook credentials. It worked! **Why can't I use environment variables for these credentials?** I'm using Heroku, and I double checked to make sure they were set. I used an initializer in my local environment, and the were correctly set there as well.

Here's my implementation in my callbacks controller: (note, I use Facebook as an optional integration after a user has already registered for an account.)

```
class Vendors::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        @vendor = current_vendor
        uid = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["uid"]
        fb_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]
        @vendor.update_attributes(:uid => uid, :fb_token => fb_token)
        redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path
    end
end
```

Any help here is appreciated. I'd prefer not to hardcode my credentials and check them into source control if possible!

Comment: How did you set those ENV variables on Heroku? Did you use **[this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)**?

Comment: Yep, used that pattern `heroku config:set FACEBOOK_APP_ID=123456789`.

Comment: You mentioned that you double-checked that they were set.  Could you describe exactly what you did to double-check?

Comment: In the console: `ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']` `# => 123456789..`

Comment: Also used `heroku config:get FACEBOOK_APP_ID`

Comment: Weird. What about if you log the ENV app/secret variables (or just part of them if you don't want them in your logs in their entirety) in your callbacks controller above? How about checking their values within the devise.rb initialiser? If they show up in your logs, does it help if you set them per-request? i.e. in your `devise.rb` initialiser change it so it's `config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'], :setup => lambda { |env| env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = ENV['APP_SECRET'] }` and you can set options[:client_id] to ENV['APP_ID'] there too if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get request variables which are not the same as environment variables. You can access your environment variables through ENV hash. Make sure they are present by outputting them into console `puts ENV['KEY']`.

Comment: Actually those request variables are coming from omniuath callback via Facebook. My environment variables are accessed in the devise initializer. As I said in my question, I've already checked and re-checked to make sure the ENV variables are set.

Comment: Double check  your environment variables again. The error message returned by facebook is pretty clear: "Error validating **client secret**."

Comment: I checked it in both development and production multiple times. I re-set `APP_SECRET` multiple times with no results.